# How To Set Up a Proxy by Passing Through Connection Through ssh to Server

Tags: ssh, networking, proxy, port, shadowsocks

Hello and thanks for taking a look.

I want to set up a proxy to have my torrent client and browser connect through it. I don't want to use squid on ubuntu server since it does http proxy protocol and all network from torrent client or browser to there is unencrypted. Even if I can make https work, I don't want to leave something open for 27/4 with plain text authentication or none at all.

I have heard of connecting to the server through ssh and then open a local port to pass all connection through it to the ssh connection:

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519
ssh-copy-id user@vpsserver
ssh user@vpsserver -D 5050 -n
```

Then I can set up `127.0.0.1` on port `5050`. That way my connection should be passed from that port to the ssh, therefore acting like a proxy. My question is, which proxy protocol should I choose when per say I am configuring it in qbittorrent?
(Image of setting page below)

[image]

Should I choose socks5 or 4 for proxy protocol(or how)? As far as I know it, it should be socks5 but I have no reason as to why it is. Would appreciate if someone can explain how this pass through works and how the protocol is applied.

Lastly, if you have a better way please reply below, open to all ideas. Wish you all a nice day!

Comment: `SOCKS5` should be the right choice - it can tunnel anything. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with a proxy? Have you looked if the part of the ssh's man page for the -D option answers your questions?

Comment: I do understand the issue, but now, thanks for the concern. I did read the man page, learning that the -D sets up a socks protocol proxy that takes both sock5 and socks4.